# Retrieve item lines from suspended transactions, Microsoft Dynamics 2012 ax for POS RETAIL

Tags: c#, sdk, transactions, dynamics-ax-2012

i'm under **Microsoft Dynamics AX for Retail POS** and i'm facing an issue.

I'm wokring on a form that retrieive the suspended transactions filtred by the customer that i put in the **BlankOperations** project.

I was able to get the list of suspended transactions by customer but i can not find a way to retrieive the lines of each transaction.

After somes researchs i discover that the lines are stored in a Hexadecimal format in the database under the **TRANSACTIONDATA** field of the table **SALESTRANSACTION**.

When i convert the **TRANSACTIONDATA**  to string i get a **XML String** .

Now i'm asking if is there a way to retrieve the transaction lines based on the sdk retail.

i put a screen so you can more understand what i am trying to do.

best regards
[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanna fetch from the lines but you can start from the base tables, which are `RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE` and `RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS`.

Note that the `RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE` is a multi purpose table, which stores every "transaction" generated in the POS.

Comment: I need to retrieive the sales lines of a transaction made in the POS.

i retrieive the value of `TRANSACTIONDATA` field  in the `SALESTRANSACTION` and i display it as a string in a Messagebox, using the following code : 
`String g = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])reader.GetValue(6),0,bufferSize);`

the bufferSize refers to the `BYTELENGTH`.

Finally it retreive the sales line data in a xml string like its displayed in the attached screen. the probleme is how to extract the data of the SalesLines tag, i try to deserialize the xml string and cast it to a `SalesTransctions` object but i failed.

Comment: the following lines in the xml string are the lines of the transaction but i failed to parse the hole string deserialized to a the object `Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime.DataModel.SalesTransaction`

 with the code : 

`XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SalesTransaction));
                        StringReader rdr = new StringReader(g);
                        SalesTransaction resultingMessage = (SalesTransaction)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);`

Comment: @user3795842 Have you checked the contents of the RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRNAS table? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes it reproduce the same data of the serialized string (y), i finally extract the data i need using `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(innerXml);
                        XmlNode node = (XmlNode)doc.DocumentElement;
                        XmlNodeList salesLines = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SalesLine");`

Comment: what i figured out is that the RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS table contains the sales line after i settlement of a transaction, not before as exemple when the transaction is suspeded.

Comment: @user3795842 SO what can we do when we need Transaction information such as items and discounts and ... before settlement in code , I mean how we can get data from Suspended transaction ?